# How to store BI publisher reports output in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

How to schedule BI publisher reports to run and then to store the output PDFs to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Event Trigger in BIP.
First of all implement an oracle package that creates a record in a table,that inserts something in a table.

Comment: Hi ,i have created a function to insert a record in the db, what would be the next step and can u explain to me about the Event trigger plz.